# Unit of the daily recommended amount of calories

Tags: nutrition, measurement

Average calories required for a man are 2000 to 2200.

Is the unit calories, or kilo-calories (sometimes also called Calories)?

Answer (score 1):

That figure is in kilocalories.  A human needs about 2000 kilocalories per day.

Sometimes a kilocalorie is described as a "big calories or a "Calorie", but to me that's more confusing than helpful.